# When does the Penalty Duration on the InvokeHTTP Processor in NiFi kick in?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use the "Penalty Duration" on the Settings of the InvokeHTTP Processor.

I understand that the flow file will be penalized by this duration if the processor determines that there may be a problem with this flow file.

My question is "under what conditions during the processing of InvokeHTTP would the flow file be penalized ?"

Is it when the result is Failure, Retry ?

I did read [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/54647/what-does-penalty-duration-mean-in-nifi-processor.html) post. However, I am still not clear on the penalty conditions for the InvokeHTTP processor

I am using NiFi 1.9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invocation is attempted.  If it occurs without any exceptions being thrown then a routing decision is made.  The routing decision is what decides whether to go to success, response, retry, no retry.  This is largely based on the status code returned by the invoked web service.  However, if any exception is thrown during the invocation/response handling then the request is sent to 'failure' and is penalized.